# SQL Performance is with query to remote DB and variable condition

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I'm trying to write a query similar to this:

```
DECLARE
  last_run = DATE;    
BEGIN
  SELECT trunc(last_run_date)
  INTO last_run
  FROM job_log
  WHERE job_name = 'test_job'

 FOR data_row in 
  (SELECT * 
    FROM data_table@remote.host 
    WHERE creation_date between last_run AND sysdate)
 LOOP
   DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(data_row.id);
 END LOOP;
END;
```

The issue is, when I run the query, it takes about 15-30 minutes to complete. When I have a hard coded date in place of the last_run variable in the cursor, the query takes about 1-2 minutes. eg:

```
SELECT * 
        FROM data_table@remote.host 
        WHERE creation_date between '03-AUG-2014' AND sysdate)
```

Does anyone have any idea as to why the query takes such a performance hit when I use a variable for as part of the condition as opposed to it being hardcoded?

Thanks for any assistance

edit: I should mention that the 'job_log' table is not being queried through a remote DB, I am directly connected to it.

Comment: perhaps the "last_run" value from the query is much different (much earlier) than your hardcoded value?

Comment: Hi Tbone, when I am testing hard coded values, i'm using the same value that is stored in last_run. Both of these statements will print out the same data, the only difference is the extremely large difference in completion time

Comment: Not sure.  Maybe have your DBA check into any locks or waits for the long running block.  You can also look into SQL trace

Comment: Can you try with dynamic SQL construct such as:
v_sql := 'select ... where creation_date between ''' || last_run || ''' and sysdate';
OPEN v_emp_cursor FOR v_sql;

I think what is happen is that the "last_run" variable only has context in the local database, so the remote database returns ALL the rows from the table, and the local database does the filtering. When you do the hard-coding, the remote db is able to apply the filtering as if run locally, so will use indexes if present, and return just the required rows. By constructing the dynanic query, you get round the context issue. I think.

Comment: Hi TenG, this is what I ended up doing and it worked perfectly. Thanks for taking the time to respond though, it is much appreciated!